# Is it possible to get special Local Disk information from PHP?

Tags: php, local, disk, hard-drive

I am running my PHP code on my local computer,So ,I just want to know the PHP has any functions to get the local hard disk information.Such as the disk name , disk space,free space available .etc.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition, yes, it is possible to retrieve this information, because you can execute commands. There are a few PHP functions to retrieve information about the disk as well, check out the following links:

- [disk_total_space](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php)( $directory );
- [disk_free_space](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php)( $directory );

Retrieving the disk's name, however, needs to be done with a command. I've just booted Windows in VirtualBox and it seems the following would work:

```
if( preg_match( '~Volumenaam : (.*)~i', `fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo C:\\`, $matches ) ) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Volumenaam is Dutch for "Volumename". I only have the Dutch version of Windows, so you'd have to check what the actual string is.

Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Builtins:

- [disk_free_space()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php)
- [disk_total_space()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php)

If you need more, you can access local commands via [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).

For disk usage, you'll also find different snippets on the net, e.g. this:

- http://justynshull.com/2010/08/du2-php/, which uses [`shell_exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: Thanks,and what kind of local commands should I use to get what I wants.Another program or windows' command?? And where to output the outcome？On the web page or whatever? I am not good at PHP,so please give me some more information. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There are two functions: [`disk_free_space()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php) and [`disk_total_space()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try searching the PHP manual before you asked here?

These two functions came up very quickly for me:

- [`disk_total_space()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php)
- [`disk_free_space()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php)

Further data such as the disc name may be trickier (you may need to use `system()` as per another answer here), but that should give you a start.

However, note that when PHP is running in a web site, it will have quite a lot of restrictions on what it can do; it's likely to be restricted to its local web folders for any disc access.

Comment: thanks.I tried it via google search and maybe my wrong keywords,I didn't get what I want.So, I thought I should ask someone to get my first step ahead.

Answer (score 0):

For the Disk Name you can use this function

```
function GetVolumeLabel($drive) {
  // Try to grab the volume name
  if (preg_match('#Volume in drive [a-zA-Z]* is (.*)\n#i', shell_exec('dir '.$drive.':'), $m)) {
    $volname = ' ('.$m[1].')';
  } else {
    $volname = '';
  }
return $volname;
}

echo GetVolumeLabel("c");
```